# How do I extract a single bit out of a std_logic_vector and convert it to an integer?

Tags: vhdl

I am struggling with type conversion in vhdl. I am pretty new to vhdl and apologize, if this is a really stupid question. 
But what i want to do is, i want to go through the input vector and add all bits together to form an integer.
For example "11001010" shall result in 4 (or "100"). And "11101010" would result for example in 6 (or "110"). How can i achieve that?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity xyz is
    port(
        input: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        output: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behaviour of xyz is
    signal temp : integer := 0;
begin
    evaluate_input :process is
    begin
        for i in input'left downto input'right loop
            temp <= temp + to_integer(unsigned(input(i)));
        end loop;
    wait;
    end process;

    stop_simulation :process is
    begin
        wait for 100 ns; --run the simulation for this duration
        assert false
            report "simulation ended"
            severity failure;
    end process;
end xyz;
```

Comment: actually you code doing that b y using  ` to_integer` method

Comment: @mooga when i replace to_integer(unsigned(input(i))) by to_integer(input(i)), i get the compiler message: test.vhdl:20:41: prefix is neither a function name nor can it be sliced or indexed

Comment: and that's correct because you can't convert from std_logic_vector to integer directly you have to convert to signed or unsigned first before converting to integer

Comment: @mooga but compiling my code, i get the message: test.vhdl:20:50: conversion not allowed between not closely related types

Comment: I just found a different solution to my problem, but i would be still interested in, how i would've been able to achieve it with this idea

Comment: Your code has another error - the final end statement has the entity name and not the architecture name (IEEE Std 1076-2008 3.3.1 "If a simple name appears at the end of an architecture body, it shall repeat the identifier of the architecture body.").  There's also `temp <= temp + to_integer(unsigned'("") & input(i));` where the type of the (empty) string literal convertible to a bit string is provided explicitly by a qualified expression. The element of input is concatenated with an unsigned length 0 and converted to integer.

Comment: `"11101010" would result for example in 6` I'm assuming that is a typo? I count five '1's

Answer (score 2):

Don't think to complicated. You want to calculate the hamming weight.

```
for i in input'range loop
  temp <= temp + (1 when (input(i) = '1') else 0);
end loop;
```

Or with your proposed way:

```
for i in input'range loop
  temp <= temp + to_integer(unsigned(input(i downto i)));
end loop;
```

`unsigned(...)` needs an array of `std_logic_vector`. By using just `i`, you get a single `std_logic`. Whereas, `i downto i` creates another `std_logic_vector` of length 1, which can be used in `unsigned`.